# Angular 4 rc.2 `Renderer.animate()` method replacement

Tags: angular

Before 4-rc.2 changes there was `Renderer.animate()` method that i used to remove page loader (that is not part of angular app and shows before angular is loaded) with fade animation like this

```
const loaderElement = bodyElement.querySelector(this.loaderSelector);

const loaderFadeOutAnimation = this.renderer.animate(
    loaderElement,
    {
      styles: [ { opacity: 1 } ]
    },
    [
      {
        offset: 1,
        styles: {
          styles: [ { opacity : 0 } ]
        }
      }
    ],
    300,
    0,
    'ease'
);

loaderFadeOutAnimation.onDone(() => loaderElement.remove());

loaderFadeOutAnimation.play();
```

How this can be achieved now with new Renderer class or other tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved with angular 4.2+

```
import { AnimationBuilder, animate, style } from '@angular/animations';
...
const loaderFadeOutAnimation = this.animationBuilder.build([
  style({ opacity: 1 }),
  animate(200, style({ opacity: 0 })),
]);

const loaderFadeOutAnimationPlayer = loaderFadeOutAnimation.create(loaderElement);

loaderFadeOutAnimationPlayer.onDone(() => loaderElement.remove());

loaderFadeOutAnimationPlayer.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

*At the time of this writing, Angular is at 4.0.0 (invisible-makeover).*

`renderer.animate()` isn't supported anymore from 4.0 onwards because animations have been decoupled from `@angular/core` and now in their own package `@angular/animations`.  I've searched myself for an answer to this and have not found any public APIs; however, there is an [`Animation` class](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/animations/browser/src/dsl/animation.ts) which is undocumented that might do the trick. It has a private method called `create` which would give you the `AnimationPlayer` that `renderer.animate()` used to return.

You can access that class now via `import { ɵAnimation as Animation } from '@angular/animations/browser';`. Like I said, it's undocumented, but looking [at the spec](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/animations/browser/test/dsl/animation_spec.ts) might hint at some way you could utilize it. I cases where AnimationMetadata needs to be provided, all that can be built with the same functions used by the Angular Animations DSL, e.g., `animate`, `style`, and so on.

Having said all of the above, private APIs are subject to change, of course, so take this information with a grain of salt. My guess is that it won't be long before computed animations return in some other form; this is probably just a transitive state due to animations being decoupled.

Incidentally, `Renderer` is also deprecated. `Renderer` will still be injected, but moving to `Renderer2` is probably the right way to move as you upgrade.

Hope this helps!